# Can I extend the undefined object like any other object?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a method for the `String` object that checks if it's undefined:

```
String.prototype.isDefined = (str) => typeof str === 'undefined';
```

Although, if the string is undefined I can't use this method or the JavaScript will break (and also it will always be true). I wonder if I can extend the undefined object in a similar fashion. I tried:

```
undefined.prototype.isDefined = () => false;
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I know I could write a function, but the purpose is cleaner, more easily readable code.

Comment: whole concept doesn't make sense. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to get rid of this function:  isDefined: (obj, value) => {
  if(typeof obj === 'undefined'){
   return !value;
  }else{
   return value;
  }
 },

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. `undefined` is not an object, it's a value.

You can't possibly write a function that checks if a string is undefined. If it's undefined, it's not a string. It's undefined.

I don't see what is not clean or readable with

```
function isDefined(x) { return x !== undefined; }
```

Comment: i can even do `isDefined (x)  =>  x !=== undefinded;`

Comment: Actually, that syntax is quite broken. I suppose you mean `var isDefined = x => x !== undefined;`.